# How to remove unnecessary additional underline on hover from active navigation links?

Tags: css, navigation, hover, underline

I have some CSS defining an animated underline style upon hover, for my navigation links. Currently, this applies to inactive links on hover, which is perfect. Active links retain this underline as well. The issue is that this code also applies to active links that *already* have this underline.

This creates an additional underline on top of the existing one, making it twice as thick in appearance. Is there something that can be tweaked in my navigation CSS to fix this? Once a link is active, I'd prefer the underline to remain static and unchanged.

```
body .active-link>a, .text .active-link>a:visited {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   margin: 0 11px;
   padding: 0 !important;
   }

.horizontal-navigation-bar nav ul li a:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   height: 1px;
   width: 0;
   background: transparent;
   transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
   }

.horizontal-navigation-bar nav ul li a:hover:after {
   background: #000;
   width: 100%;
   }
```

For reference, my site is: www.tylercharboneauprofessional.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *simplest* fix is to...

```
.horizontal-navigation-bar nav ul li a:after {
  margin-bottom: -1px;                             /* ... add this line */
```

(make them overlap and simply don't care.)

Comment: Hey @Roko C. Buljan - thanks for the input! Indeed, that does seem to be the quickest way to solve my problem, and worked perfectly. Another pesky problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector.  This will target `anchor` tags that do **not** have the class `active-link`.

```
 .horizontal-navigation-bar nav ul li a:not(.active-link):hover:after {
       background: #000;
       width: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Unfortunately this also removed the underline state for inactive links upon hover

Answer (score 0):

You have to target the active link not to display background on the :after pseudo element. add this at the end of your code. Hope it helps.

```
.horizontal-navigation-bar nav ul li.active a:hover:after {
    background: none;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the input. Unfortunately this didn't quite work as desired, as it nullified the animated underline by hovering over inactive links. I accepted Roko's answer above.

Comment: Did you replace your code with this or added the code after. Because this is meant to target only the active link. You are meant to add this code after the hover code.

Comment: oops, like I misunderstood you there! Sorry about that. I did in fact replace the code instead of adding this to my existing code. However, since I don't see any functionality drawbacks currently with Roko's suggestion, I think I'll stick with that. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Tell the selector to not use the background if the `<a>` is descended from the active link.

```
.horizontal-navigation-bar nav ul li.active-link a:after {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a selector for the active link on the `<li>`

so use that to negate the underline

`.active-link a:after { background: transparent; }`